# matching consecutive pairs in pd.Series

Tags: pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a DataFrame which looks like this :-

```
ID | act
 1    A 
 1    B
 1    C 
 1    D
 2    A
 2    B 
 3    A
 3    C
```

I am trying to get the `IDs` where an activity `act1` is followed by another `act2`, for example, `A` is followed by `B`. In that case, I want to get `[1,2]` as the ids. How do I go about this in a vectorized manner?

Edit :- Expected output : For the sample df defined above, the output should be a list/Series of all the IDs where `A` is followed immediately by `B`

```
IDs
 1
 2
```

Comment: u mind posting a dataframe of ur expected output

Comment: added an edit . Please have a look

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a simple, vectorised way to do it!

```
df.loc[(df.act == 'A') & (df.act.shift(-1) == 'B') & (df.ID == df.ID.shift(-1)), 'ID']
```

Output:

```
0    1
4    2
Name: ID, dtype: int64
```

Another way of writing this, possibly clearer:

```
conditions = (df.act == 'A') & (df.act.shift(-1) == 'B') & (df.ID == df.ID.shift(-1))
df.loc[conditions, 'ID']
```

Numpy makes it easy to filter for one or many boolean conditions. The resulting vector is used to filter your dataframe.

Comment: This works wonderfully well, although I think this solution will break in case the activity tuple A,B is split across different case IDs.

Comment: Right. That case is solvable too, though. Do you want specifically the case of only 2 variables, or every permutation of the unique values in the `act` column? If the former, easiest to filter out all other values and then use this.

Comment: I want to get all the IDs where `act1` is followed immediately by `act2`. If I filter out other values, then won't that also give me ID's where `act1` happens before `act2`, and not necessarily immediately before?

Comment: Both `act1` and `act2` should have the same ID

Comment: Ok, I've edited my answer to include this condition

Answer (score 0):

Here is one approach: groupby, and don't sort, since we need to track B immediately following A, based on the current dataframe structure.

Next aggregate using str.cat

 check if A,B is present

 get the index

 pass as a list

```
(df
.groupby('ID',sort=False)
.Act
.agg(lambda x: x.str.cat(sep=','))
.str.contains('A,B')
.loc[lambda x: x==1]
.index.tolist()
 )

 [1, 2]
```

Another approach is using the shift function and filtering:

```
df['x'] = df.Act.shift()

df.loc[lambda x: (x['Act']=='B') & (x['x']=='A')].ID
```

Comment: I tried the same solution, but it's way too slow on the dataset I'm working on. Thanks for the reply

Comment: let's see if the shift method gives u some speed up

Comment: In my experiments, breaking into a Lambda function almost invariably balloons the runtime. I am currently trying to group by ID followed by creating (act1, act2) tuples for each group and then match with the tuple (A, B). Haven't found a decent way of doing this though

Comment: so when u tried it, same speed? groupby is not so speedy a process, hence the alternative. i guess you have profiled the code to see where the bottleneck is?

Comment: I have, it's the agg function call

Comment: yea, try that's why i suggested the shift. josh's solution however is more concise and faster.